# ERROR:AAPT: error: resource style/Theme.AppCompat.light.NoActionBar

Tags: flutter, android-studio

I am encountering a problem on my project build.

I am using the techno flutter.
I am using Android-Studio on Windows 11.

The error is:

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask$TaskAction
   > Android resource linking failed
     ERROR:AAPT: error: resource style/Theme.AppCompat.light.NoActionBar (aka com.example.nysos:style/Theme.AppCompat.light.NoActionBar) not found.
     error: failed linking references.
```

I have already cleared my gradle cache, used `flutter clean`, File > Invalidate caches > Clear file system chache and Local History > Invalidate and restart.

Could you please help me fixing this error ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In Android Studio:

1. CTRL+SHIFT+F
2. Enter in the search bar: `AppCompat`
3. Change `Theme.AppCompat.light.NoActionBar` to `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar`
4. Verify your versions in your `flutter/android/app/build.gradle` and `flutter/android/build.gradle` and it should work.

Comment: 3. `...light...` vs `...Light...` seems like just an arbitrary misspelling. Was it introduced by you or by some automated process ?
4. verify versions against what ?

This answer lacks contexts and if it provided any kind of help at some point, it has aged poorly.

Answer (score 0):

i face this issue don't know why but error clearly says about its location so i change styles.xml file code.

1. in flutter project go to you android>app>src>main>values>styles.xml
2. in styles.xml file change the line no 4
3. `<style name="LaunchTheme"parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">`
4. to
5. `<style name="LaunchTheme"parent="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar">`
6. and line no 15
7. `<style name="NormalTheme"parent="Theme.MaterialComponents">`
8. to
9. `<style name="NormalTheme"parent="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar">`

[image: change these lines]

[image: to this]