# ERROR:AAPT: error: resource style/Theme.Design.NoActionBar (aka com.communilifer.markclassified:style/Theme.Design.NoActionBar) not found

Tags: flutter

when I try to build a flutter android app after
rising `targetSdkVersion to 32` instead of 31

I got this error

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask$TaskAction
   > Android resource linking failed
     ERROR:AAPT: error: resource style/Theme.Design.NoActionBar (aka com.communilifer.markclassified:style/Theme.Design.NoActionBar) not found.
     error: failed linking references.
```

this is AndroidManifest.xml activity tag

```
<activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:exported="true"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
```

i searched everyWhere can't find any solution
can anyone help?

Comment: Can you show us your LaunchTheme

Comment: this link may help https://stackoverflow.com/q/72770793/10510070